# 2D Coordinate - find the length of perpendicular foot on tilted system

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]
I am given values of $x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2$, $\theta_{1}$, and $\theta_{2}$.

I want to find out the value of the `Unknown height`.

The `Unknown height` is length of the perpendicular feet between Point 2 and the line extending towards the upper right side of the page.

How can I find the length of the perpendicular feet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the distance between points $P_1$ and $P_2$:

$$
d_{12} = [(x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2]^{1/2}
$$

and note that

$$
\sin \theta_1 = \frac{\mbox{unknown height}}{d_{12}}
$$

So that

$$
\mbox{unknown height} = d_{12} \sin \theta_1
$$